# how to change css background in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am try to change the background color of slider.But my code is not working properly. Can anyone help me please?

here is my code

html

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="redColor">Change Color</a>
<input type="range" :class="{background:fillColor}" class="slider-range" id="range" value="0" name="range" min="0" step="1" max="8">
```

js code

```
     var vm = new Vue({

          el:'#app',
          data:{
            fillColor:''
          },
          methods:{
            redColor:function(){
                this.fillColor = 'linear-gradient(90deg, #f5f4f4 0, rgb(209, 39, 16) 100%)';


            },

          }

     });
```

Comment: You are setting the `class`, not the `style` on the element… although I **do** recommend setting/changing the class and then use CSS to apply the linear-gradient style to that class.

Comment: Use`style` instead of `class`

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut got it thanks...

Comment: Ask yourself — "Why am I setting the background to red?" — is it because this is now the _active_ element? because it is _invalid_? Those are states, and classes are excellent for representing states on elements. Now you might have `<input type="range" class="active"…>` where you'll be adding & removing the "active" class as needed. Then create a style in CSS that says `input.active { …linear-gradient(… }` — No more fiddling with styles in your code, which shouldn't care about style, it should care about _state_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch

```
:class="{background:fillColor}"
```

to

```
:style="{background:fillColor}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! You could use `:style` but I try to stay away from inline CSS even with scoped styling.

HTML

```
<a href="#" v-on:click="bgColor='red-color'">Change Color</a>
<input type="range" :class="bgColor" class="slider-range" id="range" value="0" name="range" min="0" step="1" max="8">

<style scoped>
.red-color {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f5f4f4 0, rgb(209, 39, 16) 100%);
}
</style>
```

JS

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        bgColor:''
    },
    methods:{
    }
});
```